# Twitter authentication api missing secret

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am trying to authenticate with twitter endpoint https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I get the following response sent to my callback script after using the login screen presented by twitter:

```
array(2) {
  ["oauth_token"]=>
  string(27) "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ["oauth_verifier"]=>
  string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I am expecting to see a value for "oauth_token_secret" - What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

After receiving oauth_token you should convert the request token to an access token by making [POST oauth/access_token request](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/access_token) with oauth_verifier value. More information [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing)